# How to create Bitmap in android from view's bottom 50dp

Tags: android, graphics, view, bitmap

I know that you can create Bitmap from the view layout using this method [createBitmap (int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config%29)

But this method creates bitmap from the top with specified width and height.

I want to achieve the same but from the bottom. So I want to create bitmap from the bottom 50 dips.

Is there some other createBitmap implementation that can help me do that? Can this one [createBitmap (Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) come handy?

Basically I want to implement the Blur effect https://github.com/PomepuyN/BlurEffectForAndroidDesign but with blurred bar placed at bottom and a list view of pictures showing behind it.